# MySql if statment not working

Tags: php, mysql

In my Details table, when the complete field is '0' I want a certain image to appear when it is '1' I want a different image to appear. At the moment only the second image is showing (when complete field is 1)
This is the code I am using:

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $isFinished= mysql_query("SELECT complete From details where user_id = $id") ?>
<p>  <img src='<?php if($isFinished) echo "correct.png"; else echo "incorrect.png"; ?>' /><a href="details.php">Details</p>
```

Any ideas would be great!

Comment: mysql_query will return `false` only if the query you're running is invalid/incorrect otherwise a resource is always returned (even if empty it will evaluate to `true`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function

```
function getOne($query){
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    trigger_error("db: ".mysql_error()." in ".$query);
    return FALSE;
  }
  if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
    return $row[0];
  }
}
```

the code

```
$sql = "SELECT complete From details where user_id = ".intval($_SESSION['user_id']);
$isFinished = getOne($sql);
?>
<p>
  <img src='<?php if($isFinished): ?>correct.png<? else: ?>incorrect.png<? endif ?>' />
  <a href="details.php">Details</a>
</p>
```

Comment: I hope you've got the idea - you can use this function not only here but every time you need a single field out of the query - a quite common task. You can create some sister functions for getting a single row, or an array of rows as well

Comment: As I have 7 tables like 'details' would I use this function if I wanted to select complete in the 7 tables and when they are all 1, it would send an email as it means the full application is complete? Is this a similar thing?

Comment: I cannot say for certain without seeing the actual tables but it seem there is something wrong with your setup. Any chance you can have all these tables merged in one?

Comment: no they need to be seperate. no worries i can open a new question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause of your query is specifying *only select records where `complete` = '1'*

So you'll only get `1` back in the results.

You should remove that from the `WHERE` clause completely and let your php IF statement decide whether `complete = '1'`

Comment: The asker does not fetch any results. It is my guess that they expect mysql_query to return false if there are no results.

Comment: as well as actually fetching the result... mysql_query will return a object of type resource, not the actual result. So this would be always true, as the result is valid if query is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement only selects entries with complete='1'. 
You should remove the "and complete='1'" from your statement.

Edite:
ALso as mentioned above your if statement only check if your query returned something or got an error.

It should be

```
if($isFinished['complete'] == '1') {echo "correct.png";}else{echo "correcy.png";}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_query` function returns `false` only when the query is invalid. It does not return false if there are zero rows.

You should use the `mysql_num_rows` function to determine if there was a row or alternatively use the `mysql_fetch_*` functions to fetch the value of complete.

Example 1 (Similar to your original (unedited) question):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1 From details where user_id = $id where complete = 1");
$isFinished = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Example 2 (Alternative):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT complete From details where user_id = $id");
$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$isFinished = $record['complete'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the whole code?

In this case  $isFinished is not the content retreived from db: mysql_query returns false if query is wrong otherwise an object where you can fetch the results.

In this case if($isFinished) is always true as the query is correct!

you miss the fetch part ater query execution!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

For example:

```
 $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT complete From details where user_id = $id");
 $isFinished= mysql_num_rows($result);
<p>  <img src='<?php if($isFinished) echo "correct.png"; else echo "incorrect.png"; ?>'     /><a href="details.php">Details</p>
```

This way if query returns one ore more rows then $isFinished is 1 or more otherwise $isFinished is 0. Your if - else should then work properly

Note i did not change the your original SQL, change it if you need.

Comment: So how could I implement the fetch part?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$result= mysql_query("SELECT complete From details where user_id = $id  and complete='1'") ?> 
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
<p>
<?php if($row['complete']): ?>
<img src="correct.png"/>
<?php else: ?>
<img src="incorrect.png"/>
<?php endif; ?>
<a href="details.php">
Details</a>
</p>
```